# SonarQube 4.5.4 "This block was duplicated by a resource that has been deleted"

Tags: sonarqube, code-duplication, sonarqube-4.5

When browsing my SonarQube Issues I found a Duplicate Block which was marked "This block was duplicated by a resource that has been deleted".

Why is this Block still marked as duplicated when the duplicate resource has been deleted (I even can't figure out in which component the duplicate code was previously)?

[image: SonarQube duplicate with deleted resource]

Edit by @Thomas: I have the same error, and it occurred when a module was renamed. The `moduleA2` (i.e. SonarQube sub-project) has all its code "duplicated" by `moduleA1`, which is itself under its previous name.

Comment: This resource is on the same project? Same project but different module? Other project?

Comment: I can't say it, because I can't figure out where the duplicate code is (doesn't show up).
Maybe it was located in a Project I have deleted (but then everything would have been duplicated), maybe it is in another module, maybe in the same ...

Comment: @DavidRACODON-QAConsultant I face same prb and we have cross project analysis disabled. And that particular project had just 2 sql files

Comment: is there any solution? m also facing same problem